# Run Arango Shell (Arangosh) on a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb, pyarango

I have set up an Arango instance on Kubernetes nodes, which were installed on a VM, as mentioned in the ArangoDB docs [ArangoDB on Kubernetes](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/tutorials-kubernetes.html). Keep in mind, I skipped the `ArangoLocalStorage` and `ArangoDeploymentReplication` step. I can see 3 pods each of agent, coordinators and dbservers in get pods.

The `arango-cluster-ea service`, however, shows the external IP as pending. I can use the master node's IP address and the service port to access the Web UI, connect to the DB and make changes. But I am not able to access either the Arango shell, nor am I able to use my Python code to connect to the DB. I am using the Master Node IP and the service port shown in `arango-cluster-ea` in services to try to make the Python code connect to DB. Similarly, for arangosh, I am trying the code:

```
kubectl exec -it *arango-cluster-crdn-pod-name* -- arangosh --service.endpoint tcp://masternodeIP:8529
```

In case of Python, since the Connection class call is in a try block, it goes to except block. In case of Arangosh, it opens the Arango shell with the error:

```
Cannot connect to tcp://masternodeIP:port
```

thus not connecting to the DB.

Any leads about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to replicate your setup and I've encountered the same error. I wasn't able to connect to the db with `arangosh` from the `Pod` and with python code from another host. I'd reckon you could also ask on the `kube-arangodb` github page: https://github.com/arangodb/kube-arangodb/issues .

Comment: Hi, I have created an issue on ```kube-arangodb``` github right now. Would want your opinion on one thing since I directly created the arangodb environment on the pod instead of doing it directly on the VM - would my issue be partially resolved if I simply install the DB on the master node instead of doing the kubectl apply installation process? I understand that the process would not be containerized in that case.

Comment: Apologies but I cannot help you with this question as I do not know arangodb. I've tried to reproduce the setup of yours to see if there is any issue on the Kubernetes side. I'd think that it could help as a workaround for a time being (provision it directly) but I cannot guarantee it in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this community wiki answer to point to the github issue that this issue/question was resolved.

Feel free to edit/expand.

---

Link to github:

- *[Github.com: Arangodb: Kube-arangodb: Issues: 734](https://github.com/arangodb/kube-arangodb/issues/734)*

> Here's how my issue got resolved:
>
> To connect to arangosh, what worked for me was to use ssl before using the localhost:8529 ip-port combination in the server.endpoint. Here's the command that worked:
>
> - `kubectl exec -it _arango_cluster_crdn_podname_ -- arangosh --server.endpoint ssl://localhost:8529`
>
> For web browser, since my external access was based on NodePort type, I put in the master node's IP and the 30000-level port number that was generated (in my case, it was 31200).
>
> For Python, in case of PyArango's Connection class, it worked when I used the arango-cluster-ea service. I put in the following line in the connection call:
>
> - `conn = Connection(arangoURL='https://arango-cluster-ea:8529', verify= False, username = 'root', password = 'XXXXX')`
>   The verify=False flag is important to ignore the SSL validity, else it will throw an error again.
>
> Hopefully this solves somebody else's issue, if they face the similar issue.

---

I've tested following solution and I've managed to successfully connect to the database via:

- `arangosh` from `localhost`:

```sh
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+ssl://localhost:8529, version: 3.7.12 [SINGLE, server], database: '_system', username: 'root'
```

- Python code

```py
from pyArango.connection import *
conn = Connection(arangoURL='https://ABCD:8529', username="root", password="password",verify= False )
db = conn.createDatabase(name="school")
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Arangodb.com: Tutorials: Tutorial Python](https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-python/)*
- *[Arangodb.com: Docs: Stable: Tutorials Kubernetes](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/tutorials-kubernetes.html)*